# How to make the CSS tooltip box disappear after hovering over it?

Tags: html, css

I have some external CSS from W3Schools:

```
/* Tooltip container */
.tooltip {
    /*position: relative;*/
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Tooltip text */
.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0;
    border-radius: 6px;

    /* Position the tooltip text - see examples below! */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 20;

}

/* Show the tooltip text when you mouse over the tooltip container */
.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
}

span:hover .tooltiptext {
    display: none;
}
```

Which should apply some rules for the folowing block of html:

```
<div class="CELL_INFO tooltip">
    <span class="tooltiptext">
        Square resources: '.$WOOD.' wood, '.$IRON_ORE.' iron ore, '.$STONE.' stone.
    </span>
</div>';
```

There you should be able to display tooltip contained in the `<span class="tooltiptext">` by hovering over the `<div class="CELL_IFNO">` and then, if you hover over that tooltip span itself (or when the cursor leaves the containing div), it should disappear. And because you are not hovering over that div anymore, the tooltip should stay hidden.

**Basicly what I ma trying to achieve is that I have tooltip, which is shown ONLY when you are hovering the parent div, not the child tooltip span itself.**

My example is not working and I have no idea how to do it by pure CSS. Can someone explain, what is goin on?

NOTE:
*When the `display: none;` property is bound to span in global, it works, but i need it to work only for spans with the "tooltiptext" class.*

Comment: This is something MineCraft related, isn't it? :3

Comment: I would bet it is not... There are so many uses of these three resources in other games! (It is really NOT MC related :3 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the space in your selector

Try `span:hover.tooltiptext` instead of `span:hover .tooltiptext`

With the space in between, it selects elements with class `.tooltiptext` which are inside `span:hover` elements.

Comment: No worries, you're welcome :-) Usually spaces are irrelevant, but in CSS selectors they have a meaning.If you have found my answer useful, you could accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Your last rule says that you want to select a `.tooltiptext` element contained within a `span`. What it sounds like you meant to do is select a `span` that has the `.tooltip` class. try this:

```
span.tooltiptext:hover {
    display: none;
}
```

or simply,

```
.tooltiptext:hover {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Well, I think I have so much to re-learn in CSS. Thanks very much!